# How multiple \t escape sequence appears different than a single \t?

Tags: javascript

In my environment `console.log("abcd\tefgh")` outputs "abcd efgh", note the single space I'm seeing.

When using two (`\t`) `console.log("abcd\t\tefgh")`, this outputs with two tabs.

Why is this the case?

Comment: `\t` is the sequence for producing a tab, so when you have it once, you get one tab and when you have it twice you (suddenly?) get two tabs. I don't see what is odd about it?

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `html`??

Comment: 2 tab will give 2 tabs only.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you hold a common misconception about what a tab actually *is*.

That's not entirely your fault: some plain text editors (particularly ones used for programming) don't actually implement tabs "correctly", and many IDEs even default to remapping the keyboard <kbd>Tab ↹</kbd> key to some number of normal spaces (ugh); but, if you spend any length of time with a word processor (or Notepad++!) then you'll soon get used to the real deal.

Tabs are not "some fixed amount of space that gets inserted into your text":

```
abcd      fegh
    <---->
      tab

abcd            fegh
    <----><---->
      tab

  ^^^ complete lies
```

It's "line the subsequent text up to the next *tab stop*":

```
|     |     |     |     |    (tab stops as configured in the current text view)

abcd  fegh
    <>
   tab

abcd        fegh
    <><---->
   tab  tab

  ^^^ sheer genius truth
```

So, if the next tab stop is not far away, you won't get much (if any!) added space from the first one… but your second tab stop has to go to the *next* tab stop, which in all cases is likely to be at least some distance further along the line:

```
|    |    |    |    |

abcd fegh
    ≷
   tab

abcd      fegh
    ≷<--->
   tab tab
```

If it helps you remember, "tab" is short for "tabulation", as in *tables*. This is how people lined up text in columns back in caveman days.

Or, take a closer look at the key on your keyboard. Is it <kbd>→</kbd>? No, it's <kbd>⇥</kbd>. It's movement towards a fixed, columnal point.

---

**tl;dr: Everything is fine. This is how [tabs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_stop) work.**

Comment: I hadn't realized that there were predefined tabstops and was under the impression that tab inserted a predefined space. Apparently a common misconception. MDN seems to call tabStop a property of the Element interface, indicating whether or not an element may retain focus from tabbing. I understand that isn't the classical definition, but I point it out because I was curious if you could perhaps add a small description of perhaps how this differs per browsers with regards to console output and in tab/window rendering.

Comment: @TravisJ Honestly, I don't know the answer to that. I just trained myself out of _ever_ expecting specific width of space from a tab character, and recommend to others to do the same .. at which point the need for such an investigation simply sublimates into the æther. :)

Comment: This is one of the arguments for tabs vs spaces for indentation, because tabstops aren't universally the same size from program to program (8 spaces per tabstop in msnotepad, customizable in VSCode), and spaces are consistent size, many people prefer spaces for this reason (and the StackOverflow rules agree)

Comment: @TravisJ I can tell you though that it has absolutely nothing to do with "tabbing" in the sense of navigating between elements with your keyboard, or with window tabs. Those are a different kind of "tab".

Comment: @Samathingamajig Actually, that argument holds very little weight, because _form_ and _function_ are to be separated so the "exact way your code looks" is not, or should not, be a consideration; the argument is _massively_ overridden by the sheer convenience and semantic unambiguity of a single magical character (tab) repurposed to mean a single level of indentation, applied recursively. Stack Overflow's rules _don't_ agree; it's just that the editor is limited by web technology. But this isn't the place for that ;)

Comment: I understand there is no correlation between tabbing to move focus and tabbing to move the cursor :) I have more experience working in IDE's than in word processors, and I think the common occurrence in an IDE is 4 spaces is what you get from a tab, generally. However, I was genuinely curious about the rendering issue and if that is something which is browser consistent or browser dependent.

Comment: @Travis: If you press the tab key and get 4 spaces, then that's not a tab. It's 4 spaces. It's a keyboard mapping, not a definition for the ASCII tab character. But many people apparently don't realise the distinction :) As for how different browsers' dev consoles render tab characters, you can go ahead and perform tests on that, that's absolutely fine :)

Comment: _"in all cases is likely to be at least some distance further along"_ lol top equivocation there from teh me

Comment: The console was certainly an aspect of interest, although minor. I will end up doing testing from this, but was just mostly curious if you were aware of rendering differences :) Mostly my curiosity with rendering revolves around implementing a tabstop inside of a contenteditable element, which is quite tangential at this point. Thanks :)

Comment: @TravisJ Oh, the OP was asking about the console, so I didn't realise you meant more generally. Tab rendering in actual content (e.g. textboxes) is usually pretty haphazard and unconfigurable, which is why SO (and all Markdown everywhere) uses spaces for indentation. Still, enjoy your testing ;)